# difference between the two datetimes in hours in php

Tags: php

i want to calculate the hour difference between the startdatetime and enddatetime  in HOURS.

The date is in format MM/DD/YYYY and TIME in HH:MM:SS format

Below is the code :

```
$strt_date  = "03/24/2014";
$start_time = "23:14:57";
$end_date = "03/25/2014";
$end_time = "07:34:55";

$datetime1 = new DateTime($strt_date $start_time);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end_date $end_time);
$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);   
$diff1 =  $diff->format('%h');
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Wan to find the diffrence between the two datetimes ....in hrs.......

Comment: Right, but what's your question? I just see a goal and code. Do you have an error?

Comment: @markrammmy: As it's currently written, your code will throw a **syntax error**. You need wrap the two variables in double-quotes or join them together by any other means: https://eval.in/127149

Comment: "The hour difference in hours"... as opposed to, say, in turnips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters to your DateTime constructors are incorrect. If you want a space between the dates and times you need to explicitly add them.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("$strt_date $start_time");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$end_date $end_time");
```

or

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($strt_date . ' ' . $start_time);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end_date . ' ' . $end_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime($row['start']);
$date2 = new DateTime($row['end']);

$duration = $date2->diff($date1);

$hours = $duration->d*24 + $duration->h + $duration->i/60;
echo  $hours.'<br> ';
```